# code is running twice after click a href

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have on main_forum.php:

```
<a href="/forum/view/28/">hello</a>
```

this goes to page process.php where is:

```
if ($page=="forum"){
    if($page_1=="view"){
        include "view_topic.php";
    }
    else{
        include "main_forum.php";
    }
}
```

on page view_topic.php is:

```
$s_id=$page_2;
$sql="SELECT view FROM forum_question WHERE id='$s_id'";
$result=mysqli_query($db_handle2, $sql);
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$viewer=$rows['view'];
...
$viewer++;
$sql="UPDATE forum_question SET view='$viewer' WHERE id='$s_id'";
$result=mysqli_query($db_handle2, $sql);
```

My problem is, when I click on a href hello SQL UPDATE should rise 1 in view column. However it rise 2. It looks the whole code runs twice.
when I change:

```
<a href="view_topic?id=28">hello</a>
```

and

```
$s_id=$_GET['id'];
```

SQL UPDATE rise 1 in view column. It is rised only once.

Comment: what's the value of $page_2?

Comment: how did you get `$page`, `$page_1` and `$page_2`?

Comment: "/forum/view/28/" $page="forum", $page_1="view", $page_2=28

Answer (score 0):

You can simple run update query to increasing count as:

```
$sql="UPDATE forum_question SET view=view+1 WHERE id='$s_id'";
```

This will work 100%. I've tested myself.

Comment: $viewer++; works correctly. however it looks two click are made,